# How to get list card of stack ? - livecode

Tags: livecode

I want to get list card and list objects of stack by name.

Before.I ask question "How to find stack of Project Browser ? - livecode".I can do it.

Now.I want to get list card and list objects of stack by name.

Can anyone show example code for me please ?

Here my code for get number of cards of this stack

```
answer the number of cards of this stack
```

But my code this error for get name card

```
answer the name of cards of this stack
```

-------I can solve this problem-------

```
on mouseUp
   put the number of cards of this stack into numC
   repeat with crd = 1 to the number of cards of this stack
      answer the name of card crd
   end repeat
end mouseUp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example that creates an array with the stack card names as keys.  Each array element contains a list of the controls for the card.

```
on mouseUp
   local tCurrentStack, tCards, tCurrentCard, tControlsA

   put "MyStack" into tCurrentStack
   put the cardNames of stack tCurrentStack into tCards
   repeat with tCardIndex = 1 to the number of lines in tCards
      put line tCardIndex of tCards into tCurrentCard
      repeat with tControlIndex = 1 to the number of controls in card tCurrentCard of stack tCurrentStack
         put the name of control tControlIndex of card tCurrentCard of stack tCurrentStack & LF after tControlsA[tCurrentCard]
      end repeat
   end repeat
end mouseUp
```

to show the controls from card "MyCard"...

```
put tControlsA["MyCard"]
```

Comment: Nice script. I had to give each card a name without spaces, otherwise the script would fail - because the expression `card tCurrentCard` can't handle a name with spaces.  I wonder if its possible to make this script more resilient to default card names like `card id 1013`

Answer (score 0):

get the cardNames of {group | stack}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

this modification of @splash21's code solves the problem of cards that do not have a name and return the long id instead.

```
on mouseUp
  local tCurrentStack, tCards, tCurrentCard, tControlsA
  
  put "MyStack" into tCurrentStack
  put the number of cards of stack tCurrentStack into tCards
  
  repeat with tCardIndex = 1 to tCards
    put  the short name of card tCardIndex of  stack tCurrentStack into tCurrentCard
    
    repeat with tControlIndex = 1 to the number of controls in card tCardIndex of stack tCurrentStack
      put the name of control tControlIndex of card tCardIndex of stack tCurrentStack & LF after tControlsA[tCurrentCard]
    end repeat
  end repeat
end mouseUp
```